# 'Time ago' display in Wordpress blog archive

Tags: php, wordpress

I am attempting to change the standard Wordpress date published to 'time ago' in the blog archive, but leave the date display inside the single posts as normal.

I have found the following function from https://mekshq.com/change-wordpress-date-format-to-time-ago/ :

```html
add_filter( 'get_the_date', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1 ); //override date display
add_filter( 'the_date', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1 ); //override date display
add_filter( 'get_the_time', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1 ); //override time display
add_filter( 'the_time', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1 ); //override time display

/* Callback function for post time and date filter hooks */
function meks_convert_to_time_ago( $orig_time ) {
    global $post;
    $orig_time = strtotime( $post->post_date ); 
    return human_time_diff( $orig_time, current_time( 'timestamp' ) ).' '.__( 'ago' );
}
```

Of course this function applies the 'time ago' change site-wide, I would like to understand how I can have this apply only in the blog archive list view, not the single posts.

Thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is checking if it is the blog page so you would need to just if you have it on a different page.

```
add_filter('get_the_date', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1); //override date display
add_filter('the_date', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1); //override date display
add_filter('get_the_time', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1); //override time display
add_filter('the_time', 'meks_convert_to_time_ago', 10, 1); //override time display

    /* Callback function for post time and date filter hooks */
    function meks_convert_to_time_ago($orig_time) {
        if (is_home() ) {
            global $post;
            $orig_time = strtotime($post->post_date);
            return human_time_diff($orig_time, current_time('timestamp')) . ' ' . __('ago');
        } else {
            return $orig_time;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is working for the main blog archive - is there a way so it covers the archive of authors and post categories too?

Comment: Ya, here is a list of more or less anything you would need. https://codex.wordpress.org/Conditional_Tags